# GStreamer RTSP Stream with Raw Bayer

Tags: gstreamer, vlc, rtsp, pygobject

I'm trying to stream raw Bayer images from a USB 3.1 camera over the network using gstreamer and display it using VLC. I've got a pipeline that looks like this:

```
self.launch_string = 'appsrc name=source is-live=true block=true format=GST_FORMAT_TIME ' \
                     'caps=video/x-bayer,format=bggr,width=5472,height=3648,framerate={}/1 ' \
                     '! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=I420 ' \
                     '! x264enc speed-preset=ultrafast tune=zerolatency ' \
                     '! rtph264pay config-interval=1 name=pay0 pt=96'.format(self.fps)
```

When I push to the gstreamer buffer like this:

```
retval = src.emit('push-buffer', buf)
if retval != Gst.FlowReturn.OK:
    print(retval)
```

I get `GST_FLOW_FLUSHING` as the return value. Not really sure what that means or why it's always flushing.
Using VLC the client and server will negotiate a connection, but VLC never receives any frames. I suspect I have some of the parameters wrong.

**Can anyone tell me what the correct pipeline is form streaming BayerRG8 data to VLC using GStreamer?**

**Is this even a thing I should be doing or should I convert to RGB before pushing to GStreamer?**

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the identity element in your pipeline in various places to see if video data is actually getting through. In my application, I "fed" appsrc through the g_signal_emit_by_name command, with the appsrc element given a name by the name parameter. Appsrc was fed 30 times per second with the above statement, with the videorate element used after the videoconvert element in the gstreamer pipeline. You will likely need to specify a framerate in order to use videorate. Also, check your max-bytes size on your appsrc. The default of 200,000 is likely too small for your video frames.